# Highlight specific keywords in the terminal as they appear

Tags: terminal, iterm2

In iTerm2 you can create triggers that highlight a line if your regex matches. This is great for some cases but I was wondering if it was possible to highlight only a word on a specific line.

The purpose of this is to help read my server logs where specific keywords can be easily pointed out. Highlighting the entire line is a bit distracting

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A Profile-based trigger can highlight as much or little of a line as you choice (via the regex).

To highlight just a "word" in a line, you can create a simple `Highlight Text` trigger, i.e.:

[image]

Results in:

[image]

Ref: https://iterm2.com/documentation-triggers.html

Below is where you will find `Triggers`
[image]

Comment: Ahh I see. The regex I was using must be selecting the entire line. Thank you!

Comment: Very helpful to highlight certain packages in stacktrace!

Comment: awesome feature and simple answer, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

As an additional usage of the selected answer, I'd like to suggest adding a tigger for "smart quotes" with the regex `[”“’‘]`

[image: Example of iTerm2 > Preferences > Profiles > Advanced > Triggers > Edit]

This will save you some day when a coworker sends you a line of code via a chat mechanism (like Slack) and the quotes get automagically "improved". The trigger won't fire as you paste/type them, but they will happen after the line scrolls up your terminal. So, it won't prevent the mistake, but it will save you time wondering why the command failed.

[image: Example of triggered smartquotes]

Comment: If you tick the "instant" checkbox to the right then it will highlight as soon as you paste the code in, which is quite handy :)

Comment: Not a bad idea. Heck, add nbsp's and other non-printables.